# Passing variable by reference to an anonymous function not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, closures, anonymous-function

I don't know why the value of the $count variable at the end is always 0, even if I pass the variable by reference and the code enters in the loop and variable is increased.

```
try {
        $count = 0;

        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            if ($request->file('file')->isValid()) {
                $file = $request->file('file');
                Excel::filter('chunk')->load($file->getRealPath())->chunk(100, function($results) use (&$count) {
                    foreach ($results as $row) {
                        $count++;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('File not valid');
            }
        }
        $request->session()->flash('alert-info', "{$count}");

    } catch (\Exception $e) { }
```

Comment: Did you tried to simply var_dump-ing it? Are those curly brackets required there?

Comment: `var_dump($count)` after `$count++` returns 1. After the anonymous function it is 0.

Comment: Is this an object? can you use a property instead of a variable? Maybe variable scoping is still valid even you pass by reference. Using a session variable?

Comment: By the way, you are not "passing" anything by reference; the closure is "capturing" a variable by reference.

Comment: If the `Excel::filter('chunk')->load($file->getRealPath())->chunk(...)` runs the function asynchronously, then the closure will not have run by the time you output the value of `$count` later in this function (i.e. you output `$count` first, and then the function runs later, incrementing `$count`).

Comment: thanks @newacct, i guess you got the point

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice examples on passing variables to anonymous functions here:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php